# Subextensions of Finitely Generated Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be an extension of a field $F$, and assume that there exist $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \in K$ such that $K=F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$. Let $E$ be a subfield of $K$ containing $F$.

(I) Do there exist $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m \in E$ such that $E=F(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m)$?

(II) Assume that the previous question has (in general or in some specific example) a positive answer. Do there exist $\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_k \in E$ such that $E=F(\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_k)$ with $k \leq n$?

Any help is welcome. Thank you very much for your attention.

**Comments**. I have only a basic knowledge of field theory, which does not allow me to answer these general questions.
The only thing which is clear to me is that if $[K : F] < \infty$, then (I) has trivially a positive answer, since in this case $[E : F] < \infty$, so if $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m$ are a basis of the $F$-vector space $E$, then clearly $E=F(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m)$. As a corollary, if we assume that $K$ is an algebraic extension, then (I) has a positive answer, since being $K=F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$, we have in this case $[K : F] < \infty$. I do not know what can happen when $[K : F] = \infty$. As for (II), I have no idea at all of the answer.

Comment: You should build your knowledge of field theory then, otherwise you will likely not understand the answers given. (II) should be dependent on $E$; for some subfields $E$ the answer will be yes and for others no.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Dear Morgan, thank you very much for having pointed out to me the fact that (II) can have a positive or negative answer depending on the specific case. My level in algebra is that of an undergraduate course, let us say that of Lang's Undergraduate Algebra. If the answers to my questions involve notions beyond this basic knowledge, I will drop the subject with great humility.

Comment: On the contrary, I am not saying to drop them! I am more saying that working through concepts like this can be a great way to build up a good understanding. For example if you assume $K = F(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2})$, with the $\alpha_{i}$ both independent and transcendental over $F$, can you come up with a counterexample for (I)? Or if you consider a subfield $E = F(\beta_{1}, \beta_{2}, \beta_{3}) \leq K$, can you prove that $E = (\gamma_{1}, \gamma_{2})$ for some $\gamma_{i} \in K$? If the answer to this last is "always, yes", does that help you prove that (I) is true for all $E \leq K$?

Comment: The answer to the mathoverflow question below answers part I.  I think it is really hard as an exercise, but comments to the answer suggested it should have been left as an exercise.  You have received similar comments too, so you may wish try longer before looking at the solution.  Personally I don't think I would have been able to think it up: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21086/when-are-intersections-of-finitely-generated-field-extensions-finitely-generated

Comment: @tkf Thank you very very much for having kindly make me notice that question (I) has been already answered in a MO post! I have not yet read the solution for now, but the same fact that the question was asked on MO is quite indicative that the question is not exactly the kind of questions an ordinary undergraduate student can answer by himself!

Comment: @MorganRodgers Dear Morgan, thank you very very much for your encouraging words! I actually agree with you: the only way to learn mathematics is to try to solve problems, whether one can actually solve them or not. Anyhow, sometimes, one has to be very humble and recognize that a hard work has to done to get more concepts and notions, and to deeply understand them, before even trying to tackling the problem of interest. And I think this is the case. With the knowledge I have acquired in my basic algebra course, I cannot even answer the simpler questions you asked in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For a finite extension $A/B$ then $A$ is finitely generated (as a field over $F$) iff $B$ is finitely generated. One direction is obvious. For the other one, if $A$ is finitely generated, then consider the extension $C$ generated (over $F$) by the coefficients of the $B$-minimal polynomials of the generators of $A$, then $A/C$ is a finite extension thus so is $B/C$, and hence $A$ finitely generated gives $C$ finitely generated thus $B$ finitely generated.
- Going back to the fields in your question, let $L=E(a_{k_1},\ldots,a_{k_s})$ where $a_{k_1},\ldots,a_{k_s}$ is a minimal subset of the $a_i$ such that $K/L$ is algebraic. $K$ is finitely generated and algebraic over $L$, thus $K/L$ is a finite extension, whence $L$ is finitely generated, by finitely many rational functions in $s$ variables (the $a_{k_j}$) and coefficients in $E$. Let $D$ be the extension of $F$ generated by the (finitely many) coefficients appearing in those rational functions. Then $D=E$ (use induction in $s$ to make it rigorous)
- For part II, I don't know. In characteristic $0$ we'll have that $E$ is a finite extension of a subfield of $K$ isomorphic to $F(t_1,\ldots,t_m)$ thus (by the primitive element theorem) $E\cong F(t_1,\ldots,t_m)[\alpha]$ is generated by $m+1\le n+1$ elements.

  Is there an algorithm to check if a field like $\Bbb{Q}(x^3,y^3,x+y)$ is generated by 2 elements ?

Comment: Dear reuns, thank you very very ... much for having kindly answered my question. I have carefully read the first two points of your answer and I have worked out all the details. Wow: what a fantastic proof!!! Ad for your remark at the third point, I cannot understand why $E$ is a finite extension of a subfield of $K$ isomorphic to $F(t_1,\dots,t_m)$, with $m \leq n$. Could you give some more explanation, please? I would also very humbly suggest to replace the $a_i$ in your answer with $\alpha_i$ to make the notation consistent with that of the post.

Comment: In the second bullet $E$ is shown finitely generated by some $e_j$, taking the $t_i$  to be a minimal subset of the $e_j$ such that $E/F(t_1,\ldots,t_m)$ is algebraic, we get that  $F(t_1,\ldots,t_m)$ is the field of rational functions in $m$ variables and $E/F(t_1,\ldots,t_m)$ is a finitely generated algebraic extension thus a finite extension.

Comment: Thank you very very ... much for this clear explanation! Now I have understood. The crucial point (which I have missed before) is that if $t_1,\dots,t_m$ are a minimal subset of the $e_j$ such that $E/F(t_1,\dots,t_m)$ is algebraic, then $t_1,\dots,t_m$ must be algebraically independent over $F$. Indeed if not, then some $t_i$, let us say $t_m$, is algebraic over $F(t_1,\dots,t_{m-1})$, and so $F(t_1,\dots,t_m)$ would be an algebraic extension of $F(t_1,\dots,t_{m-1})$.

Comment: But since $E/F(t_1,\dots,t_m)$ is algebraic, then we would conclude that $E/F(t_1,\dots,t_{m-1})$ is algebraic, against the minimality assumption. We use this same observation in the inductive proof of the equality $D=E$ in the second bullet. So $F(t_1,\dots,t_m)$ is isomorphic to the field $F(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ of rational functions in $m$ with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: It is now clear that we must have $m \leq n$. A formal proof is the following. A maximally algebraically subset of the $\alpha_i$ is a transcendence basis of the extension $K/F$. Since $t_1,\dots,t_m$ are algebraically independent over $F$, we must then have $m \leq n$. @reuns Is this the argument you had in mind? Sorry if I am so hesitant, but I am just a beginner in abstract algebra.

Comment: The question of reuns at the end of his answer is extremely interesting for me!!! Obviously I have no idea of the answer. But by taking into account his comments above, it seems that @MorganRodgers can teach us something about the subject. Will he do?