# Can $\mathbb{Q}(x^3,y^3,x+y)$ be generated by only two elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$ be the field of rational functions in the variables $x, y$ with rational coefficients, and consider its subfield $K=\mathbb{Q}(x^3,y^3,x+y)$. Do there exist $p, q \in K$ such that $K=\mathbb{Q}(p,q)$? If the answer is positive, can you explicitly find such two elements?

This question was asked by reuns in his remarkable answer to my previous post [Subextensions of Finitely Generated Fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902911/subextensions-of-finitely-generated-fields). If I should follow my intuition, I would bet that the answer is negative, but I have no idea of a possible proof. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $K={\bf Q}(x,y)$.

Because $(x+y)^3-x^3-y^3=3xy(x+y)$ so that $xy\in K$ and $x=(x^3+xy(x+y))/((x+y)^2-xy)$.

Comment: Dear @ReneSchoof thank you very much for having answered my question! It was actually easier than I have imagined! Anyhow, I am quite convinced that in general question (II) of my previous post [Subextensions of Finitely Generated Fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902911/subextensions-of-finitely-generated-fields) has a negative answer. I will create a new post to discuss the issue.