# A computation in the field of rational functions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, rational-functions

In Dummit and Foote 3 ed., Chapter 14, Section 2, Exercise 30, I am asked the following:

> Let $ k $ be a field, $ k(t) $ the field of rational functions in the variable $ t $.  Define the maps $ \sigma $ and $ \tau \in Aut(k(t)/k) $ by
> $$
> \sigma f(t) = f \left( \frac{1}{1-t} \right) \quad \tau f(t) = f \left( \frac{1}{t} \right)
> $$
> for $ f(t) \in k(t) $.  Prove that the fixed field of $ \langle \tau \rangle $ is $ k \left( t + \frac{1}{t} \right) $, the fixed field of $ \langle \tau \sigma^2 \rangle $ is $ k(t(1-t)) $; determine the fixed field of $ \langle \tau \sigma \rangle $ and $ \langle \sigma \rangle $.

The only part of this I am struggling with is the fixed field of $ \langle \sigma \rangle $.  Call this fixed field $ E = k(s) $, where $ s = P(t) / Q(t) \in k(t) $ is some rational function.  **Note**, I am making an assumption here that $ E $ is of the form $ k(s) $, and so far cannot justify this *a priori*.  I have shown in a previous exercise from the last chapter that $ [k(t) : k(s)] = \max \left\{ \deg P(t), \deg Q(t) \right\} $, so, since $ k(t)/k(s) $ is a Galois extension ($k(s)$ being the fixed field of a subgroup of automorphisms), I expect
$$
\max \left\{ \deg P(t), \deg Q(t) \right\} = [k(t) : k(s)] = |\langle \sigma \rangle| = 3
$$
All I have been able to accomplish at this point was brute-force equation-solving by computer, setting
$$
s = \frac{a_3 t^3 + a_2 t^2 + a_1 t + a_0}{b_3 t^3 + b_2 t^2 + b_1 t + b_0}
$$
and solving the equations resulting from $ \sigma s = s $.  I thereby found the element $ s = \frac{t^3 - 3t + 1}{t(t-1)} $.  Hence I am inclined to conclude that $ k \left( \frac{t^3 - 3t + 1}{t(t-1)} \right) $ is the fixed field of $ \langle \sigma \rangle $.  **This approach feels inelegant, and I would like to know what tools I might have used to avoid an unsatisfying and opaque computer-search.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $G$ a finite subgroup of $Aut(k(t)/k)$ then the fixed subfield is $k(t)^G=k(a_0(t),\ldots,a_{|G|-1}(t))$ where $\prod_{g\in |G|} (X-g(t))=\sum_{m=0}^{|G|} a_m(t) X^m$.

Then take any non-constant coefficient $a_m(t)$, because each $g(t) = \frac{e_g t+b_g}{c_g t+d_g}$ is a Möbius transformation we get that $a_m(t)$ has at most $|G|$ poles counted with multiplicity (including the pole at $\infty$), thus $[k(t):k(a_m(t))]\le |G|=[k(t):k(t)^G]$ which implies that $$k(t)^G=k(a_m(t))$$

Edit by OP: for this problem, the technique produces the element $ a_2(t) = \frac{t^3 - 3t + 1}{t(t-1)} $, reifying the computer calculations.

Comment: Am I reading this right? Are you saying that the fixed field is always generated by the trace of $t$ in the extension $k(t)\supset k(t)^G$? This is certainly not the case, if $G$ is of order two, and $\sigma(t)=-t$.

Comment: Yes you are right, tks, no idea how to repair this

Comment: In specific cases, I always try the norm first, then the trace, and if neither works, I thrash and flounder.

Comment: @Lubin In fact the fixed subfield is $k(a_m(t))$ for any non-constant coefficient, right ? Because $a_m(t)$ has at most $|G|$ poles so $[k(t):k(a_m(t))]\le |G|$

Comment: @Lubin please confirm that I'm not crazy :-)

Comment: I cannot speak to the general case, but I can say that this approach *did* work for finding the element $ \frac{t^3 - 3t + 1}{t(t-1)} $ that I found by computer.  At the very least, this is a great technique for generating *some* elements of a fixed field, and in particular it works for my problem, so thank you.  I will accept this answer if no one comes up with a more general approach, in a day or two.

Comment: I’ll think about it, @reuns , but I’m not geometric enough to understand the pole-counting argument.

Comment: @Lubin $$(-1)^m  a_{|G|-m}(t) =\sum_{S\subset G,|S|=m} \prod_{g\in S} \frac{e_g t+b_g}{c_gt+d_g} =\sum_{S\subset G,|S|=m}  \frac{ (\prod_{g\in S}(e_g t+b_g))(\prod_{g\not \in S}(c_g t+d_g))}{ \prod_{g\in G}(c_gt+d_g)} = \frac{P_m(t)}{Q_m(t)}$$ with $\max(\deg(P_m),\deg(Q_m))\le |G|$ so if $a_m(t)$ is non-constant then the $k(a_m(t))$-minimal polynomial of $t$ divides $Q_m(X) a_m(t)-P_m(X)$ which has degree $\le |G|$

Comment: I'm quite sure the same argument works for non-Galois extensions, ie. any field $F$ between $k(t)$ and $k$ is $F=k(a_m(t))$ with $a_m(t)$ any non-constant coefficient of $t$'s minimal polynomial, but we'll need to count the number of poles on $M$ the smooth curve whose function field is the normal closure.

Comment: Got it, @reuns: very nice.